# I can not remove a printer from cups

Tags: printing, uninstall, 22.04, cups-lpd

It tried to remove 2 printers from CUPS on my laptop with Ubuntu 22.04. I managed to remove one of two printers (via http://localhost:631/printers/). The other printer I try to remove via http://localhost:631/printers/, can not deleted. What am I doing wrong? Is there something corrupt on my system?

Answer (score 2):

Always make sure cups is stopped when you alter printers. Maybe that is your issue but it will be difficult to tell you what is wrong with only this information.

However you can do this from your Linux system. Stop cups and make a backup of `printers.conf`.

```
sudo service cups stop
cd /etc/cups/
sudo cp printers.conf printers.confOLD
```

To list all printers do:

```
lpstat -v
```

and using the listed printer ID this will remove a printer (change it for your printer ID):

```
sudo lpadmin -x {printerID}
```

Then start cups again with:

```
sudo service cups start
```

Comment: my printers.conf was not in /var/cups but in /etc/cups

Comment: sorry my bad :D

Comment: I did a lpstat -v before "sudo service cups stop" which listed my printers. After I stopped the service and copied printers.conf, I could not remove the printer with "sudo lpadmin -x <my printerid I wanted to remove>. But when I started the service again and listed with 'lpstat -v" the printer I wanted to remove was gone. Probably there was someting corrupt on my system and the removal was already initiated by my attempt via CUPS GUI in the browser. Anyway problem solved. Thank you!

Comment: @user2588998 glad you got it sorted. Only issue I tend to have with cups is when I forget to stop it.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the printer reappeared after a reboot.